# Cursor showing outside in android xml

Tags: android, xml

Hi In My Application I have username and password with two edittext boxes.edittext's are displaying as rounded rectangle.
Now clicking mouse of the first edit text cursor showing outside.I want to show that cursor inside

Can any please help me.

**login.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:background="#339999"
        >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv0"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Login Form"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"

        />
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="UserName"

         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
         android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText 

        android:id="@+id/username" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:cursorVisible="true"


        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        android:singleLine="true">
    </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText 

        android:id="@+id/password" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        android:singleLine="true">
    </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbShowPwd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/show_pwd" />

    <Button 
        android:text="Login" 
        android:id="@+id/login" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text=""
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**round.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"

        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
        <size 
            android:width="5dip" />  
        <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    </shape>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add padding to your edittext.
It will alter your design. Place your textviews accordingly to make the form look good.

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:background="#339999"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Login Form"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="UserName"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbShowPwd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show pwd" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Login" >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Dhina where i need to add this padding